# How do I install JChemPaint?

Tags: installation, 12.10, java

**JChemPaint** is a Java-based software designed for molecule editing. Please tell me how to install it so that I can make a desktop icon for it. I have the java file downloaded so where do I go from here to achieve this?

Comment: I moved this from an answer to a comment since I realized it doesn't specifically answer your question about the .tar.gz file. At JChemPaint on GitHub, the most recent JChemPaint was available as a .jar file, which you can run with `java -jar ./jchempaint-3.3-1210.jar`. Do you need to compile it yourself rather than run the jar?

Comment: No I don't actually. I just thought the tarball was all there was available. But I would like the program to be **installed** instead of just able to be run via the executable file. I've modified my question accordingly so you can answer this in the form of a "answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have jar file, you can run it:

1) From the command line with `java -jar ./jchempaint-3.3-1210.jar`.

2) Or through a jchempaint.desktop file, which you can place in `/usr/share/applications` so it will show up in Dash and be able to be locked to the Launcher.

The .desktop file would look like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=JChemPaint
Comment=Chemistry 2D Modeler
Exec=java -jar path/to/install/folder/jchempaint-3.3-1210.jar
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Science
```